# Issue with CSS in the layout. Flip all the adjacent divs without affecting the layout

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm creating a dashboard in which the graph flips to show more textual details.
I've 3 adjacent graphs. I did write code to flip it successfully. But this happens properly only with my first div. When I try to apply the same logic to the next two adjacent graphs, the output doesn't looks that great. It is spoiling my whole layout. A [replica is fiddled here.](https://jsfiddle.net/pepkz7am/). I suspect the mother div with `display:flex` to be the culprit, since I'm not well versed with CSS3.

I just want the same thing happening in the first graph to happen in the second and third graphs.

Here is the HTML code that flips correctly 
HTML

```
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="chart2"></div> 
<div id="chart3"></div>
```

when I try to do the same to chart2 & chart3, it messes up. I even tried changing class names and making a seperate CSS for the other graphs. But, failed.
Following is what I tried.
HTML

```
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS :

```
.GraphBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
margin-top:2%;
padding:2% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
//margin-top:2%;
padding:0% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart1{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart2{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart3{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#patternAnalysis{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}



#purchase{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

#tam{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

.flipcard {
  position: relative;
  width: 31.33%;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 500px;
}
.flipcard.v:hover .front, .flipcard.v.flip .front{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flipcard.v:hover .back, .flipcard.v.flip .back{
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.flipcard.v .back{
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .front, .flipcard.h.flip .front{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .back, .flipcard.h.flip .back{
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipcard.h .back{
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flipcard .front
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .back
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #424242;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: table; 
}

.flipcard .back p{
    color:#fff !important;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
    font-family:'times new roman';
    font-size:1.5em;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that once you give all graphs the `.flipcard` treatment, everything is `position: absolute`, which means that these elements don't contribute any height. This causes the whole top part to have zero height.

I made the following changes:

- To the HTML:

  - changed the charts to all use the flipcart structure (copied from your question)
- To the CSS:

  - changed the `.GraphBackground` padding to `2%` on all sides, and `justify-content: space-between`, just to space the cards out evenly (this has nothing to do with fixing your particular problem)
  - removed the `width:31.33%;` from `#chart2` and `#chart3` (they should have the full width of the container, which is the card)
  - removed `position:absolute` from `.flipcard .front`, which is the most important change because it means that the `.flipcard` now has an intrinsic height again
  - added `top: 0` to `.flipcard .back`, because with the `.front` no longer being absolutely positioned, the `.back`'s default position is below the `.front`, so we have to specifically move it to the top.

Here is the version with these changes applied:

```js
var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});


var chart2 = c3.generate({
bindto:'#chart2',
     data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});

var chart3 = c3.generate({
bindto:'#chart3',
     data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});
```

```css
.GraphBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
margin-top:2%;
padding:2% 2% 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.imageBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
//margin-top:2%;
padding:0% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart1{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart2{
height:auto;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart3{
height:auto;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#patternAnalysis{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}



#purchase{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

#tam{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

.flipcard {
  position: relative;
  width: 31.33%;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 500px;
}
.flipcard.v:hover .front, .flipcard.v.flip .front{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flipcard.v:hover .back, .flipcard.v.flip .back{
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.flipcard.v .back{
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .front, .flipcard.h.flip .front{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .back, .flipcard.h.flip .back{
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipcard.h .back{
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flipcard .front
{
  /*position:absolute;*/
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .back
{
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #424242;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: table; 
}

.flipcard .back p{
 color:#fff !important;
 padding:5px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:20px;
 font-family:'times new roman';
 font-size:1.5em;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.1.29/c3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.1.29/c3.css"></link>
<div class="GraphBackground">

<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="imageBackground">
<div id="patternAnalysis"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="purchase"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="tam">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First (the biggest problem): you absolute positioning front panel and back panel, which means that no size is computed for both element. remove one of the absolute declaration (in my fiddle, it's the front one) and positioning the back panel to be at top left.

Second: Follow the first chart 1 HTML structure. I think you know this already, but just in case you don't know,

Third : #chart2 and #chart3 to follow #chart1 css

https://jsfiddle.net/pepkz7am/6/

```
.flipcard .front
{
  //position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .back
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #424242;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: table; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/epfLqkbq/1/

Main points:

- `.GraphBackground` needs a set `height`
- you had set the width of both `.flipcard` and the `#chart`. Instead, you can simply give `.flipcard` a `flex` value of 1
- to space things out nicely, add a `margin` to `.flipcard` and use `justify-content` property on the parent.

Let me know if I missed anything!

Comment: It was me who missed much :D I've little knowledge in CSS3, hence flex! Thank you for the answer, it works pretty well exactly as the solution that I already chose.

Comment: The accepted answer is nicer as it avoids setting a height on the parent wrapper. Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

Please refer fiddle[Fiddle

```js
var chart1 = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart1',
    data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});


var chart2 = c3.generate({
bindto:'#chart2',
     data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});

var chart3 = c3.generate({
bindto:'#chart3',
     data: {
      columns: [
        ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
      ]
    }
});
```

```css
.GraphBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
margin-top:2%;
padding:2% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
//margin-top:2%;
padding:0% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart1{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart2{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart3{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#patternAnalysis{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}



#purchase{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

#tam{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

.flipcard {
  position: relative;
  width: 31.33%;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 500px;
  min-height:320px;
 
}
.flipcard.v:hover .front, .flipcard.v.flip .front{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flipcard.v:hover .back, .flipcard.v.flip .back{
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.flipcard.v .back{
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .front, .flipcard.h.flip .front{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .back, .flipcard.h.flip .back{
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipcard.h .back{
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flipcard .front
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .back
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #424242;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: table; 
}

.flipcard .back p{
 color:#fff !important;
 padding:5px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:20px;
 font-family:'times new roman';
 font-size:1.5em;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#chart2,#chart3{width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="GraphBackground">

<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
   <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
   <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
   <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!--<div id="chart2"></div>
<div id="chart3"></div>-->

</div>
<div class="imageBackground">
<div id="patternAnalysis"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="purchase"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="tam">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
</div>
```

][1](https://jsfiddle.net/Ritwika/mgyr1895/)

Answer (score 0):

When trying your Fiddle and applying your html structure below:

```
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

To other charts:

```
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything works the same as the first chart in terms of flipping things, the only issue I see is the width of the chart is reduced,

[image]

this is caused by your `#chart2` and `#chart3` width properties in your CSS which both have a `width` of `31.33%` whereas `#chart1` has a `width` of `100%`.

Setting your `#chart2` and `#chart3` widths to 100% fixes that issue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've created an updated jsFiddle. The elements now flip but the background needs to be positioned a little better. https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/pepkz7am/3/

Width was adjusted:

```
#chart2{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f8f8ff;
  display:block;
  margin-left:2%;
  padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart3{
  height:auto;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f8f8ff;
  display:block;
  margin-left:2%;
  padding-bottom:2%;
}
```

Comment: I was already struck at this point exactly. Thank you for the answer any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Had to make some changes to you code :

Please find the solution here :

https://jsfiddle.net/pepkz7am/8/

html:

```
<div class="main-content">
<div class="GraphBackground">

<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flipcard h">
    <div class="front">
     <div id="chart3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="back">
      <p>lorem epsum asd dfse fsdfseesgdgr</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear-fix"> </div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="imageBackground">
<div id="patternAnalysis"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="purchase"><img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
<div id="tam">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vadymmarkov/Fakery/master/Images/logo.png"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
html,body{
  height : 100%;
  background : green;
}
.main-content{
  display : flex;
    height : 100%;
  flex-direction : column;
}

.GraphBackground{
clear : both;
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
margin-top:2%;
padding:2% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#e1e5e8;
//margin-top:2%;
padding:0% 0 2% 2%;
box-sizing: border-box;
display:flex;
}

.imageBackground img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart1{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart2{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#chart3{
height:auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding-bottom:2%;
}

#patternAnalysis{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}



#purchase{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

#tam{
height:auto;
width:31.33%;
background-color:#f8f8ff;
display:block;
margin-left:2%;
padding:2% 0 0 0;
}

.flipcard {
  position: relative;
  width: 31.33%;
  height: auto;
  perspective: 500px;
}
.flipcard.v:hover .front, .flipcard.v.flip .front{
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
.flipcard.v:hover .back, .flipcard.v.flip .back{
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
.flipcard.v .back{
  transform: rotateX(-180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .front, .flipcard.h.flip .front{
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.flipcard.h:hover .back, .flipcard.h.flip .back{
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.flipcard.h .back{
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.flipcard .front
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #f8f8ff;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.flipcard .back
{
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  background-color: #424242;
  /*padding: 10px;*/
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  display: table; 
}

.flipcard .back p{
    color:#fff !important;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20px;
    font-family:'times new roman';
    font-size:1.5em;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.clear-fix{
  clear : both;
  display : block;
}
```